# Watin UploadiFy

Tags: watin, uploadify

I am using WatiN for browser automation. But today i ended up in a problem where i need to call the flash object (uploadify button) in my asp.net page.

This code seems working fine, but doesn't show any actions

```
Element ele = window.Element(Find.ById("uploadifyUploader"));
ele.Click();
```

Is there a way to achive this in WatiN.?

Answer (score 1):

Watin is not able to access flash objects.
You can try [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/) library.
Or use javascript library. For example this: http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashjscommand/